# Why does it add two strings instead of one?

Tags: string, dictionary, set

Here's my source code:

```
destinations={"",}
destinations.discard("")
flightterminals={"Terminal 1":[],"Terminal 2":[], "Terminal 3":[]}
proceed="yes"
count=0
flightnumber=int(input("How many flights do you want to add: "))

for i in range(flightnumber):
  count+=1
  print("Where is plane {} headed?".format(count))
  temp=input("")+"1"
  destinations.add(temp[:-1])
  while ((temp in flightterminals["Terminal 1"]) or (temp in flightterminals["Terminal 2"]) or (temp in flightterminals["Terminal 3"])):
    temp=temp[:-1]+str(int(temp[-1])+1)
  print(type(temp))
  print(temp)
  flightterminals["Terminal {}".format((count-1)%3+1)]+=temp

print(flightterminals["Terminal 1"])
```

and here's the terminal:

```
Flight Terminal Manager 5600
How many flights do you want to add: 1
Where is plane 1 headed?
x
<class 'str'>
x1
['x', '1']
```

It appears that the third-to-last line, `flightterminals["Terminal {}".format((count-1)%3+1)]+=temp`, adds two strings to a set inside my dictionary although `temp` is shown to be just one string in the previous line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in the dictionnary are lists. In the line you're talking about, you are using `+=` operator. Thus, `temp` is considered as a list and its elements are pushed at the end of the corresponding list in the dictionnary. You have to use `append()` : `flightterminals["Terminal {}".format((count-1)%3+1)].append(temp)`

Comment: To clarify, I was talking about why it prints out two strings instead of one. If I input `x`, it should print `x1`, not `1, x`.

Comment: That's what i explained. `value` contains `[x,1]`. Thus, `print(", ".join(sorted(value)))` outputs `1, x` and not `x1` as expected.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the issue. Please look at it again, thanks!

Comment: Oh got it. The elements in the dictionnary are lists. In the line you're talking about, you are using `+=` operator. Thus, `temp` is considered as a list and its elements are pushed at the end of the corresponding list in the dictionnary. You have to use `append()` :
`flightterminals["Terminal {}".format((count-1)%3+1)].append(temp)`

Comment: Thanks. Btw if you change your answer to that, I'll make it the accepted answer.